# How can I add comment in one-to-many table doctrine 2.0

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I want add comment to column at table, I arranged for basic columns.

How can I add comment for entity that has many-to-one or one-to-many relation?

```
namespace Console\Entity;

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Console\Repository\UserMessage")
 * @Table(name="user_message")
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class UserMessage {

    /**
     * @Id 
     * @GeneratedValue 
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Console\Entity\Message", cascade={"all"})
     */
    protected $message;

    /**
     * @Column(name="is_read", type="boolean",options={"comment":"Is Read"})
     */
    protected $isRead = false;
```

Comment: A "one-to-many" is always an inverse relationship. It doesn't point to a concrete column.

Comment: Doctrine does not support options and comments on `@JoinColumn`. If you are using Doctrine Migrations you could write the SQL for the comment yourself, though. You just have to be careful as sometimes Doctrine will use the coment to mark internal behavior, e.g. something like `DCType`, to ensure a field will be treated as a certain doctrine type.

Comment: Please read with detail what is described in the documentation:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html